# Why is my soft ban on Pokemon go lasting more than two hours?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have gotten to the point where my Pokemon go account won't spin poke stops or catch Pokemon at all they always flee, so I looked it up and saw soft ban and lasts 30 mins, I waited for 30 mins then went back on however still could not catch Pokemon or spin pokestops, it has been two hours and I still can't do this. Could someone please tell me why?

Comment: Any idea what caused the softban in the first place? it sounds like you might have a bigger issue to deal with

Answer (score 0):

A soft ban takes roughly around 4 hours.

After that you should be fine.

First of all i would look into what got you softbanned so you can deal with that first.

You next ban could be a perma ban, which i think you dont want.

The main reason and the most common reason for soft ban is gps spoofing or just suspicious gps activity.

So if you know what you have done i would say stop it because the next could be a perma ban meaning all your progress is lost.

If you dont know i would say check your character on places and see if it jumps around, there might could be an issue with your gps.

For me i could set the gps mode to gps only by doing these steps.

Android
1. Settings
2. Location
3. Mode

Ios
I dont know, if some reader suggests an edit i would put it here.

Set it to gps only to see if the issue persists